# If $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$ then $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, radicals

I am stuck on one question and sincerely have no idea how to proceed. Let $K$ be a field containing $\Bbb{Q}$ such that $[K : \Bbb{Q} ] = 2$. Prove that there exists a square free integer $d$ such that $K=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$. Any hint to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT 1:** If $x\in K-\Bbb{Q}$ then $1$, $x$ and $x^2$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb{Q}$ because $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$.

**HINT 2:** This implies there exist $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $ax^2+bx+c=0$, and so
$$(2ax+b)^2=b^2-4ac.$$

Comment: It actually doesn't matter they're distinct.

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What I got from hint is $x$ is algebraic over $Q$ and also it is evident then [ $Q(x) : Q$ ] = 2 . So, K=$Q(x)$. But how to proceed now. Have I use your hint correctly?

Comment: @Believer $K = \Bbb{Q}(x)$. Then express $x$ in term of $a,b,c$

Comment: @Servaes Suppose $K$ is an extension field of $F$ and $[K:F]=n$. If $a\in K$, then $1,a,\dots,a^n$ are linearly dependent regardless they are pairwise distinct. If you are tied to *sets* of vectors rather than *lists* of vectors, then consider that if $a^h=a^k$ with $h\ne k$, then there's an easy polynomial that has root $a$.